# USB avr programmer problem

Tags: usb, programmer

I have this [programmer](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=12&products_id=54&zenid=7fce8002ad10e871506c9e2b741ee7bb). It works fine with their custom software and on windows. But when I try to use it on linux it shows errors. Its some kind of avr-doper clone I think. Don't know for sure.

I am running it into the hid mode. But i get this error

```
rick@Abigail:~$ sudo avrdude -F -t -c stk500v2 -p m16 -P /dev/hidraw0
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set attributes for device "/dev/hidraw0": Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Any ideas what to do? I have also tried /dev/usb/hiddev0. But it still doesn't work. The manufacturer says I sure use robokitsusbprog, but that results in device not found. Any ideas? It also has a serial mode. But that shows this error

```
rick@Abigail:~$ sudo avrdude -F -t -c stk500v2 -p m16 -P /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:1d.0-usb-0\:1.3\:1.0
avrdude: stk500_2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
```

Here is the demsg outputs for when I add the HID jumper

```
rick@Abigail:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 9246.117266] usb 2-1.3: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[ 9246.297138] generic-usb 0003:20A7:0264.0005: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Device [Robokits Robokits USB Programmer] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0
```

And this is when I remove the HID jumper

```
rick@Abigail:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 9295.220180] usb 2-1.3: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 10
[ 9295.343748] usb 2-1.3: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x1 is Bulk; changing to Interrupt
[ 9295.343758] usb 2-1.3: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 is Bulk; changing to Interrupt
[ 9295.358656] cdc_acm 2-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Also it does work in windows as an hid device

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried to run this on a 64bit machine with 32 bit Ubuntu 10.10 on it, it worked with that. Any guess why its not running on the native 64bit OS?

Comment: Rick, the horizontal scroll bars don't make for easy reading. Could you add a few line breaks?

Comment: FYI: your link to the programmer seems to require a login

Comment: @kenny its not so for me. I don't know why that is happening to you

Comment: You say it works on native 32bit linux? and not on 64bit linux? This sounds like you may be missing some essential 32bit dev packages, on my 10.10 64bit I had to install ia32-libs to get some 32bit SW working correctly

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar. It looks like it's a bug triggered by some combination of the OS, libUSB (in avrdude), and LUFA (the USB code in the programmer). This link might help: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=99674&start=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the brltty package - this is a known bug.

Comment: I did try that, no luck. I tried to run this on a 64bit machine with 32 bit Ubuntu 10.10 on it, it worked with that. Any guess why its not running on the native 64bit OS?

Comment: Yeah I had to `apt-get purge brltty`  too (kubuntu 11.10). Just removing it without stopping it might not be enough. First stop brltty, then purge the package. I understand you already purged the package, in that case a reboot is the easiest way to get rid of all brltty stuff that is still in memory.